# rngd does not run when started remotely

Tags: ssh, remote

I am trying to increase the entropy of several Ubuntu 13.04 ec2 instances by running

`ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ... user@host "sudo rngd -r /dev/urandom -o /dev/random -t 10"`

from a remote box. However rngd does not seem to do anything until I log onto the vm. At least if I log on and immediately run `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` it gives numbers around 150. After a few seconds it gives numbers in the 3000's. If I use ssh to run `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` remotely without having logged on the I get results around 150 as well.

Is this a general daemon issue of something rngd is doing?

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was using `"` instead of `'`. As far as I understand using `"` causes the shell to interpret the string when running the ssh command on the local machine. I'm not sure what was being passed to the remote machines, possible the result of the command. `'` will cause the shell to pass the string unaltered.

```
ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ... user@host 'sudo rngd -r /dev/urandom -o /dev/random -t 10'
```

works. In the end I decided to use haveged instead:

```
ssh -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ... user@host 'sudo apt-get install haveged'
```

Is all that needs to be done. It will install haveged, start it and add an entry to cause it to start on boot.

Comment: The difference between `'` and `"` is only that `$var` and `$(command)` are interpreted inside double quotes but `$` is interpreted literally inside single quotes (also backslash and backquote are not interpreted literally inside `"`). With the code you posted, `"` and `'` are exactly equivalent, so this wasn't the problem.